# Any good Subversion virtual appliance recommendations?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm looking for a quick-and-dirty solution to this, I have to set up a Subversion server really quickly, like by the end of the day tomorrow.  My initial thought was to just download a virtual appliance that we could load onto our host machine.  The problem I am having however is that all the appliances I have found so far are stuck in svn version 1.4 or lower.

Does anybody know of an appliance that has svn 1.5 running?  I don't need any of the other bits like issue tracking, WebSVN or any of that stuff.

Thanks,
Wally

***EDIT:
To answer some of the questions, I would prefer for the host OS to be some flavour of Linux so that I can avoid having to purchase an additional Windows license.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply go with installing SVN, and using the SVN Daemon, and completely ignoring Apache.  There should be no appliance needed.  Very simple to install, very easy to configure.  Just take a vanilla windows/linux box and install the subversion server.  It'll probably take all of 1/2 and hour to set up.

Answer (score 11):

You should consider this, it is really ZIRRO friction and it integrates well in
various scenarios. 
Not to mention it is free of charge.

http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Cheers,

Dragos

Answer (score 3):

No need to use an appliance, use the free [BitNami one click Subversion installer](http://bitnami.org/stack/subversion)  (supports Linux, Windows, Mac...)

Comment: Just to clarify, you can also download VMWare appliances and access cloud images from http://bitnami.org/stack/subversion

Answer (score 1):

I second the Visual SVN Server suggestion. It packages SVN with an Apache server (with SSL support!) and a really nice, easy to use control panel. You can be up in running in less than 10 minutes. It even integrates with Active Directory or your local Windows accounts very nicely.

http://www.visualsvn.com/server/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure this is what you want, but [Tigris.org](http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=91), which hosts the Svn project, has an [MSI installer for Subversion 1.5](http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=91). It includes bindings for Apache.

Perhaps you could also clarify what OS your host machine is running, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Just download and install VisualSVN Server. The installation procedure is very simple, see the [Getting Started guide](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/). VisualSVN Server is based on the latest Subversion versions, has great performance and provides unique features such as [distributed Subversion repositories](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) and [modern web user web interface](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/svn-web-interface/).

Downloading and installing VisualSVN Server does not require registration. You can easily deploy VisualSVN Server in the cloud. E.g. in MS Azure or AWS.

Answer (score -1):

I would agree with [Kibbee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1862/kibbee).  I wanted to jump in with SVN so I installed the daemon and had everything up and running in no time.  It took me longer to get all the commands down for adding and committing files than the installation.

Answer (score -1):

With Appliance, we normally think about something like this:

http://www.garghouti.co.uk/vmTrac/

There is not much info about versions and such though.
But as others have pointed out, it is dead easy to install svn and svndeamon on an server that already exists, Svn takes very little resources, and can easily be put on an fileserver. Apache is not needed at all.

Answer (score -1):

**WANdisco have just launched a Subversion Appliance:**

http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/appliance/

**They have a free webinar at:**

http://www.wandisco.com/webinar/subversion

Some of the marketing blurb:

> Download, Turn on, Use 
>   WANdisco's Subversion MultiSite Software
>   Appliance provides immediate, real and
>   tangible benefits to organizations by
>   minimizing ongoing maintenance and
>   administration costs and dramatically
>   reducing deployment time. A globally
>   distributed IT organization can
>   literally be up and running in
>   minutes. Just download it, turn it on,
>   and it works. Features: Includes
>   Subversion, Apache, a fully supported
>   version of Linux and WANdisco's unique
>   multi-site replication technology that
>   allows distributed developers to
>   collaborate at LAN-speed over a WAN,
>   instead of working in silos. Combines
>   the zero-latency deployment offered by
>   hosted Software as a Service (SaaS)
>   solutions for Subversion, with all of
>   the flexibility, control and security
>   of traditional behind the firewall
>   implementations. Eliminates
>   environmental dependencies, making
>   installation, deployment and ongoing
>   maintenance a snap. Fully supported
>   Just Enough Operating System (JeOS)
>   based on Linux provides everything
>   needed for deployment under a VM, or
>   on industry standard hardware.
>   Available for any target
>   virtualization environment including
>   VMware ESX, Citrix XenServer, and
>   Windows with Hyper-V. Ongoing
>   maintenance and support are also
>   dramatically simplified with automatic
>   updates for all appliance components,
>   including Subversion, Apache, Linux
>   and WANdisco. There's no more one-off
>   manual upgrades and patches. An entire
>   multi-site implementation can be
>   monitored and administered from a
>   single location. Sites can be brought
>   online, or taken offline for
>   maintenance without disrupting user
>   access. Built-in continuous hot backup
>   and automated recovery features
>   virtually eliminate downtime, making
>   third party disk mirroring solutions
>   unnecessary. Transparent
>   implementation approach doesn't change
>   Subversion's functionality, so no user
>   retraining is required.
>    Supported

**Supported: 
VMware (R) Virtual Appliance
VMware (R) ESX Server Virtual Appliance
Microsoft (R) VHD Virtual Appliance
Citrix XenServer (TM) Appliance
Virtual Iron Virtual Appliance
Installable ISO/CD/DVD (directly on the server)**

Comment: Neither the appliance link nor the webinar link work. 404.

Answer (score -1):

[Jumpbox.com](http://www.jumpbox.com/) has completely set up virtual appliances for 'virtually' all kinds of applications including Subversion.

Answer (score -1):

The Turnkey community appliance looks very good (though I have not tried it yet)
http://www.turnkeylinux.org/revision-control